A hook form supabase is not importing properly
This project is a Spotify clone.
the hook is not importing.  the error message says : React Hook "useSupabaseClient" is called in function "useloadArtistImage" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".
Github:  https://github.com/Jananisankar21419/spotify_2.0

useLoadArtistImages.tsx
import { Artist } from "@/types";
import { useSupabaseClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-react";

const useloadArtistImage = (artist: Artist) => {
  const supabaseClient = useSupabaseClient();
  if (!artist) {
    return null;
  }
  const { data: imageData } = supabaseClient.storage
    .from("images")
    .getPublicUrl(artist.picture);
  return imageData.publicUrl;
};

export default useloadArtistImage;

ArtistItem.tsx
"use client";
import useloadArtistImage from "@/hooks/useLoadArtistImages";
import { Artist } from "@/types";
import Image from "next/image";

interface ArtistItemProps {
  data: Artist;
  onClick: (id: string) => void;
}
const ArtistItem: React.FC<ArtistItemProps> = ({ data, onClick }) => {
  const imagePath = useloadArtistImage(data);
   
  const handleClick =(id: string) =>{
console.log(id);
onClick(data.id);
  };
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => handleClick(data.id)}
      className="relative group flex flex-col items-center justify-center rounded-md overflow-hidden gap-4 bg-neutral-400/5 cursor-pointor hover:bg-neutral-400/5 transition p-2 "
    >
      <div className="relative aspect-square w-full h-full rounded-md overflow-hidden bg-neutral-400/5">
        <Image
          className="object-cover"
          fill
          src={imagePath || "/img/avatar.jpg"}
          alt={data.author}
        />
      </div>
      <p className="truncate w-full font-semibold text-center">
        {data?.author}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ArtistItem;


need some help with hooks which not importing from supabase
edit:
i corrected the typo, but the hook is not fetching the data still, I think its not typo .
when I try to run localhost:3000/artists
in my terminal I shows
{ code: '42P01', details: null, hint: null, message: 'relation "public.artist" does not exist' } ```


You've a typo, useloadArtistImage should be named useLoadArtistImage (capital "L" as in "useLoadArtistImage") so it is a correctly named React hook and can call other React hooks. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

@DrewReese thanks for replying, i corrected the typo, but the hook is not fetching the data still, I think its not typo . when I try to run http://localhost:3000/artists ,   in my terminal I shows  {
code: '42P01',
details: null,
hint: null,
message: 'relation "public.artist" does not exist'
}

What do you mean by "when I run localhost:3000/artists in my terminal", what is this? What exactly are you doing to reproduce the issue? Where in the code is the issue? Can you [edit] to provide more complete details and likely a more complete [mcve] so we can see what data is passed to the ArtistItem component and useloadArtistImage hook?

can you check if your storage bucket is public or private? Docs

There are a couple of mistakes here.
1). The custom hook named as "useloadArtistImage":

Renamed the function to "useLoadArtistImages" to follow the convention
for custom hook names starting with "use" and then PascalCase with
your custom hook description starting with capital a letter
(useSomething).

2). When fetching data, it does not wait for data to be returned:

Make sure you are handling fetching data asynchronously.

useLoadArtistImages.tsx:
import { Artist } from "@/types";
import { useSupabaseClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-react";

const useLoadArtistImage = (artist: Artist) => {
  const supabaseClient = useSupabaseClient();
  if (!artist) {
    return null;
  }
  
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const { data: imageData, error } = await supabaseClient.storage
        .from("images")
        .getPublicUrl(artist.picture);

      if (error) {
        // Handle error if needed
        console.error('Error fetching image:', error.message);
        return null;
      }
      
      return imageData.publicUrl;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching image:', error.message);
      return null;
    }
  };

  return fetchData();
};

export default useLoadArtistImage;

